# How to single-click on a NSTextFieldCell in NSTableView to edit it?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

The default is double click. How can override it?

Answer (score 3):

One way to implement single click behavior is to over-ride the `setAction` method.  Here is an example of doing that for NSTableView which allows the user to edit one column from any row of the table by clicking on it once:

SingleClickAppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface SingleClickAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet NSTableView *theTable;
    IBOutlet NSArrayController *theArrayController;

    NSInteger colNumber;
}

- (void)addRow;
- (void)doClickEdit: (id)sender;

@end
```

SingleClickAppDelegate.m

```
#import "SingleClickAppDelegate.h"

@implementation SingleClickAppDelegate

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self addRow];
    [self addRow];
    [self addRow];

    [theTable setTarget:self];

    /// Single click action
    [theTable setAction:@selector(doClickEdit:)];
}

/// Add some temporary data to edit
- (void)addRow
{
    NSMutableDictionary *values = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [values setObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:colNumber++] forKey:@"col1"];
    [values setObject:@"Text" forKey:@"col2"];

    [theArrayController addObject:values];

    [values release];

    [theTable reloadData];
}

/// Action
- (void)doClickEdit: (id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"doClickEdit:");
    NSInteger row = [theTable clickedRow];
    [theTable editColumn:1 row:row withEvent:nil select:YES];
}

@end
```

Now make the bindings in interface builder:

- Create an Object of class `SingleClickAppDelegate` which will interface the above code with the GUI.
- Create an NSTableView and bind it to `theTable`.
- Bind the NSTableView **dataSource** and **delegate** to the `SingleClickAppDelegate`.
- Create an NSArrayController and bind it to `theArrayController`.
- For each column in the table:

  - Bind its Value to `theArrayController`
  - Set the **Controller Key** to arrangedObjects.
  - Set the **Model Key Path** to each key from above (in this example it's "col1" and "col2")

Save the project and compile, there should now be a table with some rows.  When a row is clicked, the second column is then editable.

Selecting anywhere in the row will always edit the column that is set in `doClickEdit:`.

Answer (score 2):

When single click action is called in `TableView` call this method for a particular cell

```
- (void)editColumn:(NSInteger)columnIndex
               row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
         withEvent:(NSEvent *)theEven
            select:(BOOL)flag
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think single-click is a good ideal. Single-click just select, and double-click do some default thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most elegant option is to subclass NSTableView as follows :

**myNSTableView.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface myNSTableView : NSTableView {

}
- (void)singleClickEdit: (id)sender;
@end
```

**myNSTableView.m**

```
#import "myNSTableView.h"
@implementation myNSTableView

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
   [self setAction:@selector(singleClickEdit:)];
}

- (void)singleClickEdit: (id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"singleClickEdit:");
   [self editColumn:[self clickedColumn] row:[self clickedRow] withEvent:nil select:NO];
}

@end
```

Instead of NSTableView, use the myNSTableview class, ie :

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "myNSTableView.h"

@interface Preference : NSPanel {
   NSMutableArray             *chargeArray; // Array of ChargeDefault objects
   IBOutlet    myNSTableView  *chargeTableView;
}
```

From IB, select the NSTableView graphical object which has been put in the NSView. Select the "Indentity Inspector" Tab, and select myNSTableView instead of NSTableView.

You are done.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than subclassing NSTableView, you can just create a cathegory.
In the header file of your view controller ( **MyViewController.h** or any file that has an IBOutlet connected to the Table View ), declare the new cathegory :

```
@interface NSTableView( OneClickEdit )
- (void)singleClickEdit: (id)sender;
@end

@interface MyViewController : NSViewController
{
     IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;
...
```

Then in the corresponding .m file ( **MyViewController.m** ) add the implementation of the cathegory outside of MyViewController implementation itself, and make that new method the action method of your table view in the viewDidLoad of your view controller :

```
@implementation NSTableView( OneClickEdit )
- (void)singleClickEdit: (id)sender
{
    [self editColumn:[self clickedColumn] row:[self clickedRow] withEvent:nil select:YES];
}
@end
@implementation MyViewContoller

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [tableView setAction:@selector(singleClickEdit:)];
....
```